In UK law, what weight does an organisation's stated keywords/values have?
I'm dealing with an organisation (a UK regulator) that claims, amongst other things to be Decent and Ethical[1]. They splash these values everywhere, their emails and website, pretty well anywhere they can fit them. I've been dealing with them on a legal basis and their behaviour has been anything but.
As a non-lawyer I've been wondering if these stated values have any legal significance?
[1] words to that effect anyway.

Ever Heard the word puffery?

Now you mention it, I guess I have and a quick look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puffery is interesting, but that link also says "it identifies futile speech, typically of a seller, which does not give rise to legal liability. In a circular manner, legal explanations for this normative position describe the non-enforceable speech as a statement that no "reasonable person" would take seriously anyway". But this organisation is not a seller, but a significant UK non-profit regulator.

... so to make explicit what I was trying to say, a "reasonable person" might very well suppose a non-profit regulator would actually mean what they claim everywhere.

Words like these are also quite vague. So even if there were some legal weight, it would be nearly impossible to determine whether someone was living up to them. Many people think Google stopped obeying their "don't be evil" motto years ago.


As a non-lawyer I've been wondering if these stated values have any
legal significance?

Probably not, particularly in the case of a regulatory organization. Mottos like that are aspirational rather than imposing legal obligations.
A court house where I sometimes practice has the motto "Liberty and Justice For All" carved into stone above its entrance, but that doesn't allow me to sue the judges or the courts for not living up to that standard.

Accepted, thanks.
